# Changing destination of SharePoint waffle tile

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, url

We have SharePoint online sites in Office 365.  When you are logged into Office 365 there is the waffle menu in the upper-left that contains tiles for all the apps you have access to.  Currently the SharePoint tile goes to https://[domain].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx.  I would like it to go to https://[domain].sharepoint.com/ instead.  Is there any way to either change the destination URL of that tile, or redirect it?  We did play with creating a custom tile, but that does not show up for everybody - only people who specifically add it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question but still there is nothing we can do about it.

But we can create a custom tile (from Office 365 Admin center) and pin it to the app launcher and this does solve this problem to some extent. 
Once the custom tile is created it will be available to everyone, users just need to pin it to the app launcher.

Thanks.